# How to set tabindex of a jQuery UI Tab Control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tabs

I want to be able to use the Tab key to tab to the jQuery UI Tab Control, but I do not see where I can set its TabIndex. I see lots of post about about the Index of the Tabs within the Tab Control but I am refering to the overall TabIndex of the Control itself.

Thank you.

Comment: Read the API. It says it in that with the active property.http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I was looking at the active property and I see how it can be used to set which tab is active but I do not see how to use it to set the overall TabIndex on the page. Can you give me an example? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I mis read the question. You could add a focus event to the links then activate the tab by the index. If you can wait a while I can supply an example.

Comment: That would be great if you could!

Comment: Sorry Joe, it apears that its not as simple as just adding the tabIndex on the tabs (JQueryUI resets the tabIndex to -1) but i did find that you can use the arrows to activate the tabs.

Comment: Did you find an answer yet? I'm having the same problem. :|

Answer (score 0):

For JQuery UI version 1.9.0 or above, you can access

```
 ui.newTab.index()
```

inside your function and get what you need.

For earlier versions use

```
 ui.index
```

That should do the trick!

Rachel :)